# Passing multiple arguments in SASS Mixin to output set of classes or single class

Tags: sass, mixins, extend, sass-maps, scss-mixins

```
$base-space: 1rem !default;

$space-map : (
    '1o9': $base-space,
    '1o8': $base-space/8,
    '1o4': $base-space/4,
    '1o2': $base-space/2,
) !default;

@mixin containers($new-space-map) {

    @each $name, $value in $new-space-map {

        .container--#{$name}{
            margin: $value 0;
        }
    }
}

@include containers($space-map);
```

This outputs 4 CSS classes.

I am trying to generate all 4 classes or only one class based on the name I pass as argument.

my output needs to be:

```
.container--1o9 {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.container--1o8 {
  margin: 0.125rem 0;
}

.container--1o4 {
  margin: 0.25rem 0;
}

.container--1o2 {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}
```

Or

```
.container--1o2 {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}
```

based on the argument I pass.

To explain further; I am trying trying to use `@include` on same SASS Map in both the ways mentioned below depending on my need:

```
@include containers(<SASS map file>); //This I achieved
```

or

```
@include containers(<any key from SASS Map>); //This I cant
```

I am stuck here and not sure if this is achievable or not. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try removing !default. I did it in Sassmeister and it worked as you expect

Comment: @Brad, what should I do if I want to output one single class. I tried `@include containers($1o9)` and it is not working. 
I am trying to use `@include` on same SASS Map in both the ways stated below depending on my need:

`@include containers(<SASS map file>);`

or

`@include containers(<any key from SASS Map>);`

Can you please send me the Sassmeister link if you have that handy.

Comment: Your mixin is outputting 4 classes. Just use the class you want to use. All 4 of these classes are in your CSS compiled file

Comment: @Brad, got it. I had different line of thought which is not achievable with current code. Thanks for clearing my thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the !Default. This will work as you expect it to

Link to sassmeister

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/2839eaf64bd441e73a92aed6bb980465

Remember all 4 classes are being compiled into your CSS file. Just use the one you want

Comment: Please post the full answer and not just a link (the link is 404)